# NetworkX betweeness centrality with argument k, endpoints

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx

I would like to ask if there is someone who could explain the meaning of arguments **k** and **endpoints** whose can be used for betweeness centrality algorithm in **networkx** module.

Here is  [link](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/centrality/betweenness.py#L22) for source code of betweeness centrality measure in networkx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### k

k is used to determine whether an approximate algorithm is used.

If k is not set, a shortest-path algorithm is run for all starting points in the graph, otherwise the shortest-path algorithm is only run for k random choices of starting point.

k therefore allows you to control the tradeoff between accuracy and speed.  A smaller value for k gives you a faster, but more approximate, answer.

### endpoints

endpoints is a boolean that controls the definition of distance.  Suppose we have points A and B that are linked by an edge.  We can think of the shortest path A to B as being 1 edge, or 2 nodes.

Setting endpoints false uses the first definition (counting edges), setting endpoints true uses the second definition (counting nodes).

Comment: and what makes difference between setting endpoints to **true** or **false** ? Also  you wrote smaller **k** gives more approximate answer. not the other way around ? That for smaller **k** computation is faster but result is not so precise as for bigger **k** ? And thanks for the answer this clarified arguments for me clearly.

Comment: You are correct about k, smaller k is faster but not as precise.

Comment: So to be correct the k represent the number of nodes right ? That for example i have the graph consisting of 10 000 nodes and a I choose k = 5000 so computation will be done only for 5000 random verticies ?

Comment: But there is possibility that for computation will be used a lot of disconected components right ?